# Java grading calculator with remainder 0's

Tags: java, eclipse, calculator

Current output has remainder 0's. Example: Theory Grade 50.00% and Final Grade 50.0%, would like to remove additional 0's and round to 50%.

Input:

```
double theoryGrade = (test + midterm + exam) * 100/70;
double practicalGrade = (assignment + lab) * 100/30;
double finalGrade = (lab + test + assignment + midterm + exam);

System.out.printf("Theory Grade %.2f%%%n", (theoryGrade));
System.out.printf("Practical Grade %.0f%%%n", (practicalGrade));
System.out.printf("Final Grade %.1f%%%n", (finalGrade));
```

Current output:

> Theory Grade 50.00%
>  Practical Grade 50%
>  Final Grade 50.0%

Sample Output #2:

> Welcome to the CST8215 Final Mark Calculator
>  Enter your Lab mark
>   out of 10: 5
>  Enter your Quiz/Test mark out of 10: 5
>  Enter your
>   Assignment mark out of 20: 10
>  Enter your Midterm mark out of 20:
>   10
>  Enter your Final Exam mark out of 40: 20
>
> Theory grade: 50%
>  Practical grade: 50%
>  Final grade: 50%

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assign1 {
    public static void main (String args[]) {

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the CST8215 Final Mark Calculator\n");

    System.out.println("Enter your Lab mark out of 10: ");
    double lab = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter your Quiz/Test mark out of 10: " );
    double test = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter your Assignment mark out of 20: ");
    double assignment = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter your Midterm mark out of 20: ");
    double midterm = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter your Final exam mark out of 40: ");
    double exam = input.nextDouble();

    double theoryGrade = (test + midterm + exam) * 100/70;
    double practicalGrade = (assignment + lab) * 100/30;
    double finalGrade = (lab + test + assignment + midterm + exam);

    System.out.printf("Theory Grade %.2f%%%n", (theoryGrade));
    System.out.printf("Practical Grade %.0f%%%n", (practicalGrade));
    System.out.printf("Final Grade %.1f%%%n", (finalGrade));
```

// This section works for Sample output#1, But I am receiving remainder 0's for sameple output #2

Sample Output #1: (Red indicates user entered information)
Welcome to the CST8215 Final Mark Calculator
Enter your Lab mark out of 10: 7.5
Enter your Quiz/Test mark out of 10: 5
Enter your Assignment mark out of 20: 18
Enter your Midterm mark out of 20: 15
Enter your Final Exam mark out of 40: 32
Theory grade: 74.29%
Practical grade: 85%
Final grade: 77.5%

Comment: What can't you use the same format specifier you did for `practicalGrade` on the other two?

Comment: Simply use `%.0f%%` for all the outputs

Comment: Enter your Lab mark out of 10: 7.5
Enter your Quiz/Test mark out of 10: 5
Enter your Assignment mark out of 20: 18
Enter your Midterm mark out of 20: 15
Enter your Final Exam mark out of 40: 32
Theory grade: 74.29%
Practical grade: 85%
Final grade: 77.5%
// I require the code to also calculate decimals like the example above.

Comment: Well, that's contradictory to your question. If you require a different format from `50%`, then you need to use a `if-else` statement

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want. If you want to round to 0 decimal digits then use `%.0f`. And [format code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: I'm getting trailing 0's for certain inputs. Example: 50.00%, how do i round it 50% ?

Answer (score 0):

use %4d instead of %.2f%%%n that would solve your issue.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double`

Comment: System.out.printf("% 4d", intValue);
make all decleration to int.
But  if you do so 50.1 will also appear as 50.